# adding google apis for android sdk

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add google apis for my android sdk so that I can use Google Maps Apis for my project.

When I go to android SDK & AVD manager and then to available packages and then select the Google Apis. They are not installed and I am getting the following error message :

```
Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 10, revision 2
File not found: C:\Android\temp\google_apis-10_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 9, revision 2
File not found: C:\Android\temp\google_apis-9_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 8, revision 2
File not found: C:\Android\temp\google_apis-8_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google USB Driver package, revision 4
File not found: C:\Android\temp\usb_driver_r04-windows.zip (Access is denied)
```

I am clueless. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the android SDK manager, make sure you run it "as administrator". I had the same problem and found that it hung when I was installing/removing additional parts after the first basic install of the SDK manager (which runs under UAC, an hence admin privileges). Nothing to do with Eclipse, although sometimes you can get the similar problems in that tool as well where the solution is to run as admin too.

Comment: thank you so much, I was searching for this issue since a while.. everything else has worked fine lol but got into trouble for Google APIs.. now it does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right privileges to install stuff in C:\Android when you use eclipse ?

Regards,
 Stéphane